# QSqlDatabase and SQLite: SELECT query not behaving as expected

Tags: sqlite, qt

I'm having trouble using SQLite in Qt. I created a table and performed a simple `SELECT` query.

```
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if (!db.open())
        return -1;

    QSqlQuery query(db);
    bool success = query.exec("create table person (id int primary key, "
            "firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20))");    // Returns true
    bool valid = query.isValid();                   // Returns false, expected true
    success = query.exec("select * from person");   // Returns true
    valid = query.isValid();                        // Returns false, expected true
    bool select = query.isSelect();                 // Returns true
    int size = query.size();                        // Returns -1, should be 0

    return 0;
}
```

Why are these queries invalid even though `query.exec` returned `true`? Why is `size` not returning 0 here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't inserted any data into the table. The documentation for `isValid()` says:

> Returns true if the query is currently positioned on a valid record;
>   otherwise returns false.

Neither creating the table, nor selecting from an empty table, returns any records, so `isValid()` is expected to return `false` in both cases.

Try inserting some data into the table.

Note that `size()` is not supported by all database backends. Use `db.driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::QuerySize)` to check if it is supported for your database. If it isn't supported, then `size()` will return -1.

Comment: That explains my first question. But why am I getting -1 as the number of rows when I run my `SELECT` query? This behavior persists even when I do `success = query.exec("insert into person (id, firstname, lastname) values (0, 'foo', 'foo')");` before I execute the `SELECT` statement. The docs also say that `size()` returns -1 *if the database does not support reporting information about query sizes*, but I'm not sure how I would verify that's the case.